# Android: NullPointerException when the application attempts to encrypt .txt file

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to encrypt/decrypt a file from my virtual device (Genymotion). I will show you the code and the exceptions that i have. I guess that the nullPointerException comes from the line where i declare `View v = null` in `onActivityResult` method but i do not know how to fix it.

Exceptions

```
07-22 13:34:10.241  10419-10419/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt, PID: 10419
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/nikola.txt }} to activity {application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getId()' on a null object reference
            at application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
07-22 13:34:10.263     765-1598/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/.MainActivity
07-22 13:34:10.350     765-1598/? E/ActivityManager﹕ Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 576x576
07-22 13:34:10.400     765-2035/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-22 13:34:10.466     765-2035/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-22 13:34:10.466     765-2035/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x9ea263c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-22 13:34:10.903      765-786/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{2ef175ff u0 application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/.MainActivity t26 f}
07-22 13:34:11.032    1006-1265/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-22 13:34:11.033    1006-1265/? W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa095a020, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-22 13:34:11.786    2640-2640/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3007(201KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 16MB/21MB, paused 301us total 21.960ms
07-22 13:34:11.808    2640-2640/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3080(224KB) AllocSpace objects, 4(252KB) LOS objects, 24% free, 15MB/21MB, paused 173us total 7.668ms
07-22 13:34:11.822    2640-2640/? I/art﹕ Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 24% free, 15MB/21MB, paused 237us total 13.937ms
07-22 13:34:12.735  10419-10419/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 10419 SIG: 9
07-22 13:34:12.738      765-823/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
07-22 13:34:12.764      765-805/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '25d12a93 application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
07-22 13:34:12.764      765-805/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '25d12a93 application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-22 13:34:12.777      765-782/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt (pid 10419) has died
07-22 13:34:12.778      765-981/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{25d12a93 u0 application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt.MainActivity}
07-22 13:34:12.778      765-981/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '25d12a93 application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt/application.nikola.com.encryptdecrypt.MainActivity (server)'
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btnEncrypt;
    Button btnDecrypt;

    final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnEncrypt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnActivity1);
        btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnDecrypt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnActivity2);
        btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent chooseFile;
        Intent intent;
        chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("file*//*");
        intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        EncryptDecrypt crypto = new EncryptDecrypt();
        View v = null;
        String filePath = null;
        switch(requestCode) {
            case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    filePath = uri.getPath();

                    switch(v.getId()) {
                        case R.id.btnActivity1:
                            crypto.encryptor(filePath);
                            break;
                        case R.id.btnActivity2:
                            crypto.decryptor(filePath);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

This is is the encrypt/decrypt algorithm that i use.

```
public class EncryptDecrypt {

    public void encryptor(String inputFilePath) {

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        File file = new File(inputFilePath);
        String keyString = "140405PX_0.$88";
        String algorithm = "DESede";
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
            fileInputStream.read(fileByteArray);
            for (byte b : fileByteArray) {
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            SecretKey secretKey = getKey(keyString);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("encrypt.file"), cipher));
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(fileByteArray);
            objectOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void decryptor(String inputFilePath) {

        String outputFilePath = "decrypt.txt";

        String keyString = "140405PX_0.$88";
        String algorithm = "DESede";
        try {
            File inputFileNAme = new File(inputFilePath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileNAme);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFilePath);
            SecretKey secretKey = getKey(keyString);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher));
            System.out.println(objectInputStream.available());
            fileOutputStream.write((byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject());
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
            objectInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static SecretKey getKey(String message) throws Exception {
        String messageToUpperCase = message.toUpperCase();
        byte[] digestOfPassword = messageToUpperCase.getBytes();
        byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        return key;
    }


}
```

Comment: In `onActivityResult` you set `View v = null;` and then without getting a `View` you call `v.getId()` in the `switch` case.

Answer (score 1):

```
    View v = null; // v is null
    String filePath = null;
    switch(requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                filePath = uri.getPath();

                switch(v.getId()) { // v is still null
                    case R.id.btnActivity1:
                        crypto.encryptor(filePath);
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnActivity2:
                        crypto.decryptor(filePath);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

your `v`is null and you are trying to do `v.getId()`. That is why you are getting `NullPointerException`.

In order to fix this, You might want to add a OnClickListener to your `btnActivity1` and `btnActivity2`.

```
   btnActivity1.setOnCLickListerner(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {                                                      
                        crypto.encryptor(filePath);
                    }
            });
    }

    btnActivity2.setOnCLickListerner(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        crypto.decryptor(filePath);
                    }
            });
    }
```

Comment: He updated the question, pointing out that he knows where the `null` is coming from, but doesn't know how to get the `View`. I had commented on the same observation right before you posted.

Comment: @DigitalNinja Yeah just saw that and I updated my answer.

Comment: I think that this code will not work for me because in this way i can not use filePath variable

Answer (score 1):

In  your `switch-case` of `MainActivity`, you are using `v.getId()` but `v` is initialized to `null` therefore you are getting `NullPointerException`

Guessing what you are trying to do is that you are trying to decide whether to decrypt or encrypt the file based on whether two of the buttons in your layout is clicked. But you are not doing it in a proper way. Use `OnClickListener` for each button and set a boolean flag to check whether to decrypt or encrypt at `onClick` event of those buttons. Then show your `FILE CHOOSER`.

You can modify your MainActivity in this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btnEncrypt;
Button btnDecrypt;
boolean encrypt=false;

final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnEncrypt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnActivity1);
    btnEncrypt.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDecrypt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnActivity2);
    btnDecrypt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.btnActivity1:
                        encrypt=true;
                        break;
                    case R.id.btnActivity2:
                        encrypt=false;
                        break;
                }
    Intent chooseFile;
    Intent intent;
    chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    chooseFile.setType("file*//*");
    intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
    startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    EncryptDecrypt crypto = new EncryptDecrypt();

    String filePath = null;
    switch(requestCode) {
        case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                filePath = uri.getPath();

                switch(encrypt) {
                    case true:
                        crypto.encryptor(filePath);
                        break;
                    case false:
                        crypto.decryptor(filePath);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the fix ! My application still doesn`t work but now i do not have NullPointerException